# Running my ASP.NET Core solutions locally, does the browser launch to URLs starting with "P://localhost..."?

Tags: asp.net, .net-core, visual-studio-2019

This doesn't happen for every ASP.NET solution I develop and run locally, but sometimes Visual Studio 2019 will launch my browser to my intended start page URL, but will prefix the URL with "P:/localhost" which obviously doesn't run.  To clarify, it looks like this:

[URL in launched browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9aXf.png)

It's as if the original URL was supposed to be "" (reasonable) but something snipped off the "HTT".  What happens is the browser thinks I'm trying to look at a local file and fails at that, too.  In fact, if I click into the URL box it shows the "file:///" prefix:

[URL in launched browser with focus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8IQt1.png)

Very weird.  I've seen this in Visual Studio 2017 as well.  I can't think of any odd configurations I might have set, any add-ons to VS, or anything peculiar about my setup that might be at cause.

#### launchSettings.json

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:11111",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "requirements/1",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "BC.Service.Requirements": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "weatherforecast",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please share us your `launchsettings.json` file?

Comment: Thanks, @Anduin.  I have added it now.